# Linear equation multiplying both sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x + 6}{3} - 9 = 4$$

[Simplified version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4qa5.png)

My question is after multiplying each side, is it not supposed to be $3x+18-27 = 12$?

Why did he not multiply $(x+6)$ also? I am confused.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.  We are sorry for not greeting you so quickly.  To master this sight will require time and patience, so do not give up on your math dreams (problems)!  Use "$" to indicate math has started and a second dollar sign to signal the end of math when typing your question.

Comment: Suppose that you have a pie that someone has cut into three pieces. If you ate three pieces, how much pie would you have consumed?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you should take L.C.M. of denominators only, divide it by respective denominator & then multiply it (quotient) with respective numerator $$LHS=\frac{x+6}{3}-9=\frac{x+6}{3}-\frac{9}{1}=\frac{x+6-9\times 3}{3\times 1}=\frac{x+6-27}{3}$$
Now, you can cross multiply with RHS

Comment: Oh, i get it. After you wrote it a different way i get why the answer is what it is now. Thank you Harish!.

Comment: What if the equation was.   x + 6 (over 3) = 4. How would you solve for x?

Comment: Very simple, you just cross multiply as follows $$\frac{x+6}{3}=4$$ $$x+6=3\times 4$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I initially taught, but what you do to one side, don't you need to do to the other. In other words don't you also multiply the left side by 3? . Or that don't apply to situations like this.

Comment: No, denominator of one side is multiplied to the numerator of other side & vice-versa. You can't multiply denominator of one side to the numerator of the same side

Comment: @ DI Kwame: I hope it helped you. If you have further query you may ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33422/discussion-between-di-kwame-and-harish-chandra-rajpoot).